# Integrate trackingjs with meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, tracking.js

I am new to meteor. I am trying to build my test app with meteor and trackingjs. I have placed all the files of trackingjs into lib/tracking folder but it gives me a lot f errors like

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.  Errors prevented startup:  While building the application: lib/tracking/assets/opencv_haarcascade_converter.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)  Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

and after removing the lib/tracking/assets folder I again get errors like :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error, your script depends upon a global tracking variable. So you have to put that in client/compatibility  folder. That way the files will be executed without being wrapped in the new variable scope.